# How to create a FieldMask object using Google Protobuf in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers

I would like to create an instance of the [Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/field-mask). I need to consume an API and it expects a `FieldMask` so that I can override certain parameters to the value I specify.

Hence the API takes a `Message T` and a `FieldMask overrideT` as arguments. I would provide the value of T and a FieldMask accompanying with the field I would like the API to use from my provided value of T.

I am currently using it by providing a value of T and a FieldMask overrideT, like so,

```csharp
T value = new T() {
fieldName = "myValue",
};

FieldMask overrideT = new FieldMask() 
{
Paths = { "field_name" }
};

// call the API with value and overrideT as parameters...
```

But it is not working. It is not throwing any Exceptions, but the API is ignoring the mask. I haven't come across any examples illustrating how to use `FieldMask`. Can someone please direct me on what should I be refering to or how should I be setting the `FieldMask` ?

Comment: "But it is not working." - can you define "not working? Does an exception get thrown? If so, what exactly does it say? Is it not throwing, but ignoring your mask? or...?

Comment: Sorry for not being precise. By not working I mean to say that it is not throwing any error, but ignoring the `FieldMask` I am setting. I have updated the question to reflect the detail.

Comment: The server needs to implement logic to extract the field mask, and perform the filtering. Have you implemented that logic on the server? Or is the FieldMask not received at all on the Server?

Comment: This the FieldMask definition for C# - https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/WellKnownTypes/FieldMask.cs

Comment: I was able to create a FieldMask using the static method `FieldMask.FromString`, I could verify it by calling the `ToDiagnosticString()` method on the Fieldmask instance.
Hence for the example code, `FieldMask overrideT = FieldMask.FromString<T>("field_name")` and `Console.WriteLine(overrideT.ToDiagnosticString())`.
I am only consuming the server by writing client code @RagHaven.

Comment: @guptaanmol184 you need to receive the field mask on the server side, by extracting it from the request, and then you can know which fields are relevant in the payload. So, construct the field mask on the client as part of the request, and then receive the fieldMask on the server, and use it as needed.

Comment: Yes @RagHaven it is working now. I am only writing client code that is sending the request, so I cannot comment on the server side handling of the `FieldMask`. The reason for my query was there are no examples in the C# Google Protobuf documentation for making use of `FieldMask`. For now I have got a way that is working for me.

Comment: @guptaanmol184 Could you post an answer to your question, then, so others can see it as well? I agree with the need for more examples.

Comment: Another example, this one in Java: https://netflixtechblog.com/practical-api-design-at-netflix-part-1-using-protobuf-fieldmask-35cfdc606518 https://netflixtechblog.com/practical-api-design-at-netflix-part-2-protobuf-fieldmask-for-mutation-operations-2e75e1d230e4

Comment: An example: https://www.azilen.com/blog/grpc-api-performance-improvement-through-protobuf-fieldmask-in-net

Comment: `// call the API with value and overrideT as parameters...` is the important part. Next time, probably indicate more specifically what methods you're calling and how.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge `(update: IMessage)` into `(value: IMessage)` using `FieldMask fieldMask`, then instead of calling `value.MergeFrom(update)`, call `fieldMask.Merge(update, value)`.

Note the reversal of the order of parameters between `IMessage.MergeFrom` and `FieldMask.Merge`.